# opencv stereo camera error

Tags: c++, opencv

i working in a stereo camera project i have two cameras 5megapixels in every one i connected it with my laptop and run my code but when i run it i get this error `libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device`
im linux os that's my c++ opencv code there are any ideas how to fix it i tried others codes i found it in network but still give me the same error

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
cv::VideoCapture cap1(1);
cv::VideoCapture cap2(2);

if(!cap1.isOpened())
{
  std::cout << "Cannot open the video cam [1]" << std::endl;
  return -1;
}

if(!cap2.isOpened())
{
  std::cout << "Cannot open the video cam [2]" << std::endl;
  return -1;
}

cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);

// Values taken from output of Version 1 and used to setup the exact same parameters with the exact same values!
cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);    

cv::namedWindow("cam[1]",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::namedWindow("cam[2]",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)    
{    
  cv::Mat frame1, frame2;    
  bool bSuccess1 = cap1.read(frame1);    
  bool bSuccess2 = cap2.read(frame2);

  if (!bSuccess1)
  {
    std::cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream [1]" << std::endl;
    break;
  }

  if (!bSuccess2)
  {
    std::cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream [2]" << std::endl;
    break;
  }

  cv::imshow("cam[1]", frame1);
  cv::imshow("cam[2]", frame2);

  if(cv::waitKey(30) == 27)
  {
    std::cout << "ESC key is pressed by user" << std::endl;
    break;
  }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux?

Comment: yes and i still did't know how to fix it

Comment: The first of all, I would reduce resolution and FPS rate. Probably, frames are processed to slow and device buffer overflowed by unprocessed data.

Comment: i tried two use my chines tablet cam as a wireless cam and it works with but slow the usb cam with out any proplems are that mean the proplem are in my laptop board ? itried to use this ode to reduce and still give me error

Comment: capLeft.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 4);
    capRight.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 4);

// Values taken from output of Version 1 and used to setup the exact same parameters with the exact same values!
    capLeft.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    capLeft.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    capRight.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    capRight.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);